# ios - trying to add the launch and application image to app, but the pList file doesn't have that row

Tags: ios, ios5

I am going through some documentation about adding the application image for the app, and it says to edit the Info.plist in Xcode, and locate the "Icon file" and edit that entry.

I am looking at the pList file, but there is no such entry. I tried making one, but it seems to only allow adding subsections via the interface. Should I just edit that file in VI or am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is the screen shot of my current pList File

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your app's target config, and drag the image to it.

[image]